# Changing the value of input field - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input-field

I've been trying to change the value of input field after I select the item from **SelectField from MaterialUI library** but I haven't succeed it yet but as far as I did search on it, everything that I wrote seems like what it is supposed to be.

This is what I use to change the value;

```
    var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs._deviceId);
    element.setAttribute('value', 'deneme');
    console.log(element);
```

This is the input field;

```
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-2 control-label">Device ID</label>
                <div className="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="deviceId" placeholder="Device ID" ref="_deviceId" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

And I consoled the **element variable** after I select the item, in order to check everything is okay and it seems there is no problem.

Here is the console log;

[image]

As you see, the value is placed successfully but on the screen, nothing happens to input field.

Comment: because the component is not rerendered > use a state member and pass it to the input <input value={this.state.value}/>. you will also need to listen the input changes to update your state accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component needs to be re-rendered after you have set the `value` attribute. React only re-renders a component when it detects a state change. So rather use a state variable-

```
//Declare the state variable

this.state = {
    inputValue: ''
};

//Use a lifecycle event or your own method to change the value of that state by using the setState method as-

someMethod() {
    this.setState({
        inputValue: 'deneme'
    });  
}

//In HTML use the above state as-
<input type="text" className="form-control" id="deviceId" placeholder="Device ID" ref="_deviceId" value={this.state.inputValue} />
```

Remember to use **setState** method to change the state so that component re render can take place.

**OR**

You can call `this.forceUpdate()` to forcefully re-render the component.